# Can I use two monitors and a tv display with mac mini?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a 2020 Mac Mini M1. I have extended a display using HDMI port for monitor 1 and thunderbolt 3 to HDMI for the 2nd monitor.

I would like to have a tv display mounted above these two displays for when I do bike workouts. I therefore only need the TV display to be active when using it.

What A/V strategy would you suggest that doesn't require me to be unplugging / plugging cables when I want to use the 3rd television display while not needing the other 2 displays?

Thanks!

Comment: HDMI and Thunderbolt/DisplayPort support pass through. You just need a monitor that has not only an input but also an output socket so you can daisy chain two monitors to one socket on your Mac minim.

Comment: ah thanks @robert

Comment: I'm assuming that whichever monitor I daisy chain the tv to will just mirror the contents of that monitor?

Comment: No when using daisy chaining each monitor gets a different signal.

Comment: I'm reading more about this and it seems there might be inherant hardware limitation of 2 monitors for the M1 chip. Not sure this is going to work actually :/ @robert